# This version of the API has been Sunset

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to push my application from cloud9 to heroku but anytime I type heroku the following error is displayed.Any help would be highly appreciated.

This version of the API has been Sunset.! Please see https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1147 for more   information

Comment: Sounds like you need to update your dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting on heroku from cloud9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169897/hosting-on-heroku-from-cloud9)