# Hosting on heroku from cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to create a new app and then push my application to heroku but any time I type `heroku create` the following error appears. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'heroku' (>= 0.a) among 392 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have the [heroku toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed?

Comment: That aside, why are you using `heroku create` to *publish* your app to Heroku? That's used to initialize a new application.

Comment: yes i want to initialize a new application so that I can push on  that but anytime   I type heroku create the above error appears

Comment: Ok, see my first comment.